# On a minimal nonsolvable group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, solvable-groups

By "minimal nonsolvable" I mean a nonsolvable group whose all proper subgroups are solvable.

Let $G$ be a finite minimal nonsolvable group, with the following properties:

1- $G$ has only one proper normal subgroup $N$,

2- $N$ is an elementary abelian 2-group;

3- $C_{G}(N)=N$;

4- $\dfrac{G}{N}\cong A_{5}$.

5- $\forall x\in G$, $o(x)\in\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5\rbrace$.

Does there exist any group $G$ with the above conditions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No such group exists.

Then assumed conditions imply that $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ or, equivalently, the conjugation action of $G$ on $N$ gives $N$ the structure of an irreducible ${\mathbb F}_2G$-module, where ${\mathbb F}_2$ is the field of order 2.

It is well-known that there are just three such modules up to isomorphisms, $N_1,N_2,N_3$, where $N_1$ has dimension 1 and $N_2$ and $N_3$ have dimension $4$.

By Condition 3, we cannot have $N \cong N_1$. But $H^2(A_5,N_2) = H^2(A_5,N_3) = 0$, so an extension of $N_2$ or $N_3$ by $A_5$ is split, and hence it is not a minimal nonsolvable group, because it has a subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt. Thank you for your answer. Could you please give a reference for the claim in the second paragraph of your answer?

Comment: The earliest reference  *I* know (for the irreducibles of $SL(2,2^\alpha)$) is the 1968 Michigan Summer School lectures of G Higman.

Comment: This is a nice proof, but it relies on knowing this classification of irreducible $\mathbb{F}_2G$-modules, which is much higher technology than everything else involved.  In particular, the question sounds like it could come from a first or second course in group theory, where one certainly wouldn’t expect most students to know that classification.  I wonder if there’s another proof that would be suitable for such a setting?

Comment: It also relies on being able to compute their cohomology groups. I would guess rather that the question comes from some kind of project perhaps at Masters level.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine so if someone proves Twin primes, it's not just fine to use it as a theorem?  I don't get your conniption.

Comment: @Danielly: Of course it’s fine to use proven theorems — as I say in my older comment, I think this is a nice answer. But at the same time, it would also be nice to know if there’s a more elementary proof.